# How to smoothen and slow down a video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

Im using this code to convert a batch of images to video :-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('C:/New folder/Images/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)


out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

The problem now is that since images are not continuously snipped but have gaps, hence the output video is very very fast.
I want a option in opencv to create the video in slow motion.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are setting the video FPS to `15` but you aren't getting that result for some reason. You could try lowering `15` down to say `5` like this:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 5, size)
```

I imagine you've tried that though, so another alternative would be to write each image to the video multiple times. For example:

```
num_repeats = 5 

for img in img_array:
    for _ in range(num_repeats): 
        out.write(img)
```

Just change the value of `num_repeats` until it results in a speed you like.

Comment: thanks that worked for slowing it down, could you also help me with fast forwarding it ?

Comment: @vinita To speed it up, I'd only add 1 frame (don't add repeating frames like I suggested above) and set the `FPS` to something higher like `60`. Try some different values until you get what you want. Also, could you mark as answered?